# Visual Studio designer does not generate code for `List<T>` members of `Windows.Forms.Control`

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-designer

The following class (a Windows Forms Control) is a type of list control,
and the `ListControlItem` don't inherit any Windows Control class.

```
public class ListControl : Control
{
    private List<ListControlItem> items;

    public ListControl()
    {
        //
        // Required for Windows Form Designer support
        //
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (components != null)
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.items = new List<ListControlItem>();
    }

    public List<ListControlItem> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set { items = value; }
    }
}
```

The problem is, at Design Time, Visual Studio tries to serialize the list content to the resource file of the Form, instead of creating the code for instantiating each item and then adding to the control like with `ListView` and `ListViewItem`.

Visual Studio design generated code for `ListControl`:

```
        this.listControl1.Items = ((System.Collections.Generic.List<ListControlItem>)(resources.GetObject("listControl1.Items")));
```

For `ListView`:

```
        System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("");
        System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("");
        System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem3 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("");
        System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem4 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("");
        System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem5 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("");
        System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem listViewItem6 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem("");

        this.listView1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem[] {
        listViewItem1,
        listViewItem2,
        listViewItem3,
        listViewItem4,
        listViewItem5,
        listViewItem6});
```

I tried to search the `ListView` and `ListViewItem` to solve the problem,
`ListView` has its "own list class" named `ListViewItemCollection` that implements the interfaces `IList, ICollection, IEnumerable`, but `List<T>` implements the same interfaces.

Does I need to implement a custom serialization for it? Maybe this would just serialize to the resources file. I can't find much documentation as it don't inherit any Windows Forms Control base classes.

**UPDATE**

Putting the attribute `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]` in the `List<T>` property gives one resource for each `List<T>` item.

```
        this.listControl1.Items.Add(((ListControlItem)(resources.GetObject("listControl1.Items"))));
        this.listControl1.Items.Add(((ListControlItem)(resources.GetObject("listControl1.Items1"))));
        this.listControl1.Items.Add(((ListControlItem)(resources.GetObject("listControl1.Items2"))));
        this.listControl1.Items.Add(((ListControlItem)(resources.GetObject("listControl1.Items3"))));
        this.listControl1.Items.Add(((ListControlItem)(resources.GetObject("listControl1.Items4"))));
        this.listControl1.Items.Add(((ListControlItem)(resources.GetObject("listControl1.Items5"))));
```

Thats like implementing a custom serialization for `ListControlItem` can help.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve? There may be another way of approaching the issue.

Comment: The same of `ListView`. Making the Visual Studio designer generate code for each `ListControlItem` instead of putting on the resource file.

Comment: AFAIK you'd need to use the [CodeDOM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) for this. This should allow you to define how code is generated into the partial designer class.

Comment: Specifically I think you'd want to use `CodeDomSerializer`, as you suspect in the last paragraph.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410216/listint-designer-serialization) is near a duplicate question, but with `Int` as the type for the `List<T>`. @Octopoid yes, the MSDN documents the `CodeDomSerializer` like you said, but only for custom types or if there is a need to serialize the property in a custom way. Otherwise it should serialize using the reflection api, so I don't think its needed. Maybe implementing a class for the `List<T>` can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's necessary to implement a `TypeConverter` for the class. What this `TypeConverter` do is just returning a constructor descriptor for the class.

Also, specify the `TypeConverter` of the class using the parameter `[TypeConverter(typeof(typeConverter))]`.

According to MSDN [How to: Implement a Type Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in this case more specifically on the *Type Converters That Generate Code for Property Initialization at Run Time*.

> The .NET Framework provides the capability to generate dynamic
>   property initialization code at design time that will initialize a
>   property at run time.
>
> Developers can build a type converter that produces constructor-based
>   initialization code. These type converters can generate constructor
>   code dynamically using values set at design time in order to configure
>   properties of a type at run time. The type converter implements the
>   logic to configure the type and values of a constructor for the
>   property.

The resulting code of the Visual Studio designer

```
        this.listControl1.Items.Add(new ListControlItem());
        this.listControl1.Items.Add(new ListControlItem());
        this.listControl1.Items.Add(new ListControlItem());
        this.listControl1.Items.Add(new ListControlItem());
        this.listControl1.Items.Add(new ListControlItem());
        this.listControl1.Items.Add(new ListControlItem());
```

The `TypeConverter` return just a no parameter constructor, but that can be changed in the `TypeConverter` code.

About the `CodeDomSerializer`

> If you need to produce code besides a constructor to initialize a
>   property, it is possible to dynamically generate code by implementing
>   a custom CodeDomSerializer and applying a DesignerSerializerAttribute
>   that associates your CodeDomSerializer for a type with the type. This
>   approach is typically used only for scenarios in which dynamically
>   controlled or customized code generation for component initialization
>   is important. For more information on this approach, see the
>   documentation for CodeDomSerializer.

That is, with the answer method, the properties values need to be passed on the constructor parameters. If is not sufficient (like setting properties not on the constructor), then it may be necessary to use `CodeDomSerializer` like @Octopoid said.